# PHP GET Request return inconsistent results

Tags: php, json

I am using cURL via PHP to test service connections, and I'm getting some inconsistent results. When I run the test via PHP & cURL this is my result:

```
{"response":"\n\n\n\n \n \n
```

When I put that same URL in my browser I get this:

```
{"response":"\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n<head>\n    <link href=\"/images/global/global.css\...and so on
```

The response in my browser is cut short, but you get the idea.

With my PHP, I read in a JSON file, parse out the URL I need and the use cURL to send a GET request. Here is the code that I am using to test the service via PHP:

```
<?php
include ("serviceURLs.php"); 

class callService {
    function testService($url){

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_exec($ch); 

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch); 
        if ($info['http_code'] == 200){
            echo("Test has passed </br>"); 
        }else{
            echo("Test Failed.</br> "); 
        }

        var_dump($info); 

        curl_close($ch); 
    }

    function readFile(){
        $myFile = "./service/catalog-adaptation.json"; 
        $fr = fopen($myFile, 'r');
        $fileData = fread($fr, filesize($myFile)); 
        $json_a = json_decode($fileData, TRUE); 

        $prodServer = $json_a['serverRoots']['%SERVER_ROOT']['PROD']; 
        $demoServer = $json_a['serverRoots']['%SERVER_ROOT']['DEMO']; 
        $testServer = $json_a['serverRoots']['%SERVER_ROOT']['TEST']; 

        $testUrls = $json_a['commands'];     
        foreach($testUrls as $tURL){
            $mURL =  $tURL['URL']; 

            if(stripos($mURL, "%")===0){
                $testTestService = str_replace("%SERVER_ROOT", $testServer, $mURL); 
                $testDemoService = str_replace("%SERVER_ROOT", $demoServer, $mURL); 
                $testProdService = str_replace("%SERVER_ROOT", $prodServer, $mURL); 

                echo ("Production test: "); 
                $this->testService($testProdService); 

                echo ("Demo test: "); 
                $this->testService($testDemoService); 

                echo ("Test test: "); 
                $this->testService($testTestService); 
            }
        }
    }
}
$newServiceTest = new callService;
$newServiceTest->readFile(); 
?>
```

Can anyone tell my why I am getting different results and how I can fix my code so I can get consistent results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set below option for return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```